# how to fetch the data from adminside and then display in client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

currently 3 vacancy available in admin side and I want to display them in client side carrer page
if admin side delete the all vacancy then display the client side no vacancy available now

admin side (use entity framework):

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult DisplayVacancyData()
        {
            var list = _dbfltEntities.tbl_vacancy.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
```

see admin side view:

[image]

client side (not use entity framework)

HomeController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Career(Vacancy _vacancy)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44325/Home/DisplayVacancyData").Result;

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

see response is ok but which logic should be apply to display the data

[image]

vacancy.cs

```
    public class Vacancy
    {
        public int vacancyid { get; set; }
        public string vacancytitle { get; set; }
        public string vacancyposition { get; set; }
        public string vacancyexperience { get; set; }
        public string vacancyjobdescription { get; set; }
        public string vacancyrequiredskil { get; set; }
    }
```

careerpage.cshtml

```
<style type="text/css">
    .actionlink {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: cornflowerblue;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 style="margin-top:150px;">Current Job Openings</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:155px;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Apply for Job", "ApplyForJob", null, new { @class = "actionlink" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p> ssss ss sss a sss s of an ss-sssss s ss? s ss with s, ssss s enthusiassm s s? s s aside s s s s s s. s over ssss s s s s s sss below:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I am trying to get the data using viewbag**

HomeController.cs

```
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                ViewBag.vacancytitle = _vacancy.vacancytitle;  //I am seeing in watch window but it is null

            }
```

accessing a view bag in career view page

```
@ViewBag.vacancytitle
```

help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return value of a function *responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()* is ignored.

Admin side (use entity framework),
add action (return json):

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetVacancyData()
    {
        var list = _dbfltEntities.tbl_vacancy.ToList();
        return new JsonResult(list);
    }
```

HomeController.cs 
(client URI "https://.../Home/GetVacancyData" )

```
   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Career()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44325/Home/GetVacancyData").Result;

          if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<Vacancy> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vacancy>>(result);
            return View(products);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

careerpage.cshtml

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <p>@item.vacancytitle</p>
    }
```

Comment: I am trying this but not work  ```List<Vacancy> products = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Vacancy>>();```

Comment: it is work but data is displaying html format but not in a career page see this watch window https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XlBc.png

Comment: your answer is work fine but issue is admin side return the json data format and I am handling also delete and edit vacancy in admin side what is solution for that see my admin panel in question

Comment: see this image data returning json format but I want to add vacancy,edit vacancy and delete vacancy admin side https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1PPU.png